# Detect touched object in View in Android

Tags: android, view

I want to detect which Object is touched inside a `View`.

Here's my `View`

```
public class TouchView extends View {
private Matrix translate;
private Bitmap image, background;
private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
private GestureDetector simpleOnGestureListener;

public TouchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    translate = new Matrix();
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.photo);

    //background = decodeFile(R.drawable.background);
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    simpleOnGestureListener = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener(this));

}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    canvas.drawBitmap(background, translate, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(image, translate, null);
    Matrix m = canvas.getMatrix();
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    simpleOnGestureListener.onTouchEvent(event);
    invalidate();
    return true;
}


private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures";
    TouchView view;

    public MyGestureListener(TouchView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        view.onMove(-distanceX, -distanceY);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }


}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        scaleFactor = Math.max(0.6f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 2.0f));

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(int resId) {
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), resId, o);
        //find the correct scale value. it should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }

        //decode wit inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), resId, o2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public void onMove(float dx, float dy) {
    translate.postTranslate(dx, dy);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Is there any way to detect if the photo is clicked or the background?
I want to make both moveable as you can see, but if I click on the Photo I want to move it manually. Not the whole View.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't completely understand what do you want. But as I found out from your code you want to show two images(background and foreground) in your view.
You need to check location of touch (using getX() and getY()). And if the foreground image rectangle contains the point, your object is touched else the background is touched.

Comment: how can i detect this?

Comment: I have written it for you: Just get x,y of the touch using getX() and getY() and then you need to check if new Rectangle(xofImage,yofImage,widthofImage,heightofImage).Contains(x,y)